# Getting permission denied error when executing Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm getting the following error when executing a select count(*) from tablename query when connected to beeline.

```
ERROR : Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException(Permission denied
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkOwner(FSPermissionChecker.java:201)
```

I can execute showtables; successfully but get this error anytime I execute a query.  I am logged in as the hadoop user that has access to both hadoop and hive.

I've granted the folder where the tables resides full permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2015-06-03 15:44 /data1
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop hadoop              0 2015-06-05 15:23 /tmp
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop supergroup          0 2015-06-05 15:24 /user
```

The table is in the user directory.
Environment details:
OS: CentOS
Hadoop: HW 2.6.0
Hive: 1.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the result for `hdfs dfs -lsr /` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a hive managed table in that case could you print what you get when you do

```
hadoop fs -ls /user
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
```

the error suggests that you are accessing a table from a user who is not the owner and seems like user does not have read and execute access

Comment: drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop supergroup          0 2015-06-05 16:28 /user/hadoop
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop supergroup          0 2015-06-03 16:57 /user/hive

Comment: drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop supergroup          0 2015-06-26 11:32 /user/hive/warehouse

Comment: The hive table is owned by the hadoop user that I am logging in with.    
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop          supergroup          0 2015-06-05 15:24 /user/hive/warehouse/contentanalyticsstaging